# Android studio 1.1.0 cannot setup Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have used Robolectric before Android 1.1.0 but I cannot use it any more after I updated it. I Googled it and tried some solutions but none of them worked. 
Here is my current settings:

project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my_package_name"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
}
```

When I try to build the project it gives me the error like below:

```
Error:(22) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android-unit-test']
   > No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
```

Of course, I have android-unit-test plugin installed and removed and reinstalled it again but no luck.

Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bad news: since Android Plugin 1.1.0 the plugin `com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1` is depricated. Also see https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test#deprecation-notice

Good news: You don't need anymore a plugin for robolectric. Just remove `apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'` and all should work like before.

Here an examples project setup https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Comment: Haha. Good thing you got here first. I was going to post that :)